# Angular material css md-autocomplete :focus

Tags: css-selectors, angular-material, md-autocomplete

I'm trying to use :focus on md-autocomplete to change the background color when the user press Keydown or Keyup.

It's work fine with :hover for the mouse :

`md-autocomplete-parent-scope:hover{
    color: rgb(63, 92, 154);
}`

but not with :focus.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it. I'm not sure it's the good solution but it's works.

```
.ng-scope .selected{
color: rgb(63, 92, 154);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When md-autocomplete is focused, then it's child element md-autocomplete-wrap has class md-menu-showing, so you can use this class and change the color for this element.

Answer (score 0):

md-autocomplete has an input element inside, so you have to :focus the input element.

```
md-autocomplete input:focus {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, this is because the `md-autocomplete` element itself does not get focus - instead it has a child input element that gets the focus.

You could try [`:focus-within`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within). However this currently does not work in IE or Edge.